# Unable to save list of dict data with cx_Oracle LOB object to a JSON file

Tags: json, blob, python-3.6, cx-oracle

I have a select query that is run via cx_oracle library. The output of this query is stored as a list of dict and it needs to be saved in a json file for future use and iterations.

But the output of this query has "cx_oracleLOB object" and because of that, I am stuck with the error "**TypeError: Object of type LOB is not JSON serializable**" and am unable to write to json file. Please find my code:

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(***)
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute(q)

col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
rv = cursor.fetchall()
json_data = []
for result in rv:
    json_data.append(dict(zip(col_names, result)))
with open("result.json",'w')as fp:
     fp.write(json.dumps(json_data))

sample output of selectquery:

[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "age": 10,
    "skills": <cx_Oracle.LOBobjectat0x00000123>
  },
  {
    "name": "def",
    "age": 10,
    "skills": <cx_Oracle.LOBobjectat0x000004456>
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the cx_Oracle documentation [Fetching LOBs as Strings and Bytes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes), create an output type handler:

```
def output_type_handler(cursor, name, default_type, size, precision, scale):
    if default_type == oracledb.DB_TYPE_CLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if default_type == oracledb.DB_TYPE_BLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_RAW, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
    if default_type == oracledb.DB_TYPE_NCLOB:
        return cursor.var(oracledb.DB_TYPE_LONG_NVARCHAR, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

connection.outputtypehandler = output_type_handler
```

This assumes your LOBs will fit in memory (and are each 1 Gb or smaller), but you seem to be making that assumption already.

Update: in the latest version of cx_Oracle ([now called python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)), you can simply set `oracledb.defaults.fetch_lobs = False` and don't need the type handler.